# SWI-prolog Semantic reasoning

Tags: prolog, owl, swi-prolog

I want to convert an owl file to prolog .owl -> .pl the documentation that found within rdfs2pl package was not helpfull any hints on how can I proceed?

gen :-
        rdf_load('C:/test/pizza.owl'),
        tell('C:/test/pizza.pl'),
        write_schema(pizza ,'http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/2009/07/sssw/pizza#',[use_labels(true)]), told.

I "consult " the file of this code and then it loops forever!

Comment: "not helpfull" is not a problem description ...

Comment: and the documentation is more than clear: https://github.com/cmungall/rdfs2pl - they show exactly how do use it from command line.

Comment: I need further examples I already tried  github.com/cmungall/rdfs2pl  the description is not very helpfull.

Comment: I don't get it ... it clear from the docs, from command line use `rdfs2pl SCHEMA_NAME INPUT_FILE_PATH -o OUTPUT_FILE_PATH` - **what exactly** does not work here for you?

Comment: If you're getting some error, please show it to us. The more details the better for people here to understand the problem